# How to pass a value from one Form to a private TextBox in another Form?

Tags: c#, winforms, class, static, public

I have `Form1` with several **private** TextBoxes. I want to pass some values from my DataGridView in `Form2` to those TextBoxes in`Form1` (when I press Enter for example).
What I want to do is to pass the values of rows of current selected `Row` in DataGridView to be passed to TextBoxes in `Form1`:

*(I know how to get the values of selected row in datagridview my question is just the title...)*

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
    SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM X WHERE ID=" +
                        dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + "", sqlcon);
    SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (sqldr.Read())
    {
        Form1.CodeTextBox = sqldr[codecolumn].Tostring
        Form1.NameTextBox = sqldr[Namecolumn].Tostring
        Form1.BlahTextBox = sqldr[Blahcolumn].Tostring                               
    }
}
```

which yells at me:

> codeTextBox is private... not able to do so because of protection
>   level...

I think I have to make a static class to do so, but I dont know how.
I would appriciate if someone would explain me that.

`Form1` Class:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
 {
    public static string searchString;

    SqlConnection sqlcon = 
       new SqlConnection("Data Source=(LocalDB)\\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter("GetInvoice", sqlcon);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sqlda.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
     }
      //Xbuton_click datagridview_blah ...
}
```

Comment: Could you show us you `Form1` class?

Comment: Try to let your `codeTextBox` instance be `public`

Comment: @D-Shih I showd the Form1. is it necessary? if its not let me know to shorten th equestion

Comment: @D-Shih Whould you please tell me how?

Comment: What is your expect to pass the data? because you use `sqldr.Read()`might read more than one-row data. I didn't see and textbox class in your `form1`

Comment: @D-Shih I want the values of rows of current sellected row in datagridview to be passed to textboxes in `Form1`.

Answer (score 2):

### Declare private variable and Form1 Constructor with parameter like :

```
private string CodeTextBox; private string NameTextBox; private string BlahTextBox;

Public Form1(string CodeTextBox , string NameTextBox, string BlahTextBox)
{
  this.CodeTextBox= CodeTextBox; 
  this.NameTextBox= NameTextBox; 
  this.BlahTextBox = BlahTextBox; 
}
```

### Assign Value to Textbox

```
txtCodeTextBox.Text = CodeTextBox;
txtNameTextBox.Text = NameTextBox;
txtBlahTextBox.Text = BlahTextBox;
```

### Call it like

```
if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Enter)
{
  SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID FROM X WHERE ID=" + dataGridView1.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value + "", sqlcon);
  SqlDataReader sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
  while (sqldr.Read())
  {
   string CodeTextBox = sqldr[codecolumn].Tostring;
   string NameTextBox = sqldr[Namecolumn].Tostring;
   string BlahTextBox = sqldr[Blahcolumn].Tostring;
   Form1 frm = new Form1(CodeTextBox, NameTextBox, BlahTextBox);
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay you have 3 code blocks, I did as you said. But it yells at me On declaring part in the first code block. it says `_the type Form1 already contains a defenition for 'codetexbox'_`. beside this you have written `CodeTextBox` variable 2 times in your first code block, 1 time in your second code block. I cant differentiate between these and other variables like it also... for example: when you said `txtCodeTextBox.Text = CodeTextBox;` what do you mean by `txtCodeTextBox.Text` and which `CodeTextBox` are you reffering to? `private string CodeTextBox;` or `Public Form1(string CodeTextBox)`?

Comment: where should I assign Value to the Textbox? where should I write this code?`txtCodeTextBox.Text = CodeTextBox;
txtNameTextBox.Text = NameTextBox;
txtBlahTextBox.Text = BlahTextBox;` in form1 or form2? (I want to understand what was on your mind and where you meant)

Answer (score 1):

try this

CodeTextBox text changed event

```
 public void CodeTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CodeTextBox.Text = ((TextBox)sender).Text;
        }
```

SqlDataReader

```
 while (sqldr.Read())
                     {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        TextBox t = new TextBox();

        t.Text=sqldr[codecolumn].Tostring;

        form1.CodeTextBox_TextChanged(t,null);

                        }
```

Comment: could you please explain me your frist code block? what does it do, what is the sender meaning?